Trouble with shiny app and installing GitHub dependency
I have a shiny app that isn't able to process the input, and additionally I can't deploy it. I am attaching the UI and server logic which I hope to get help with on the potential problem.

    library(shiny)
    library(ToxicR)
    library(readxl)
    library(devtools)
    
    # UI
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Dose-Response Modeling App"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput("datafile", "Upload Data File", accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx")),
          selectInput("datatype", "Select Data Type:", choices = c("Continuous", "Dichotomous")),
          selectInput("fit_type", "Select Fit Type:", choices = c("MLE", "MCMC", "Model Averaging")),
          numericInput("bmr_level", "Enter BMR Level:", value = 0.1, step = 0.01),
          actionButton("run", "Run Modeling")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput("results"),                        
          downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Results")
        )
      )
    )


I am able to load a csv file for analysis and pick from the dropdowns and enter the bmr value numerically, but there's no update regarding the processing and I just end up waiting forever and need to stop the run.
Here is what I have for the server:

    # Server
    server <- function(input, output) {
      results <- reactiveVal(data.frame())
      
      # Install devtools if not already installed
      if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE)) {
        install.packages("devtools")
      }
      
      # Install ToxicR from GitHub
      if (!requireNamespace("ToxicR", quietly = TRUE)) {
        devtools::install_github("NIEHS/ToxicR")
      }
      
      observeEvent(input$run, {
        req(input$datafile, input$datatype, input$fit_type, input$bmr_level)
        file_path <- input$datafile$datapath
        data <- if (grepl("\\.csv$", file_path)) read.csv(file_path) else read_excel(file_path)
        
        ids <- unique(data$ID)
        all_results <- data.frame()
        
        for (id in ids) {
          dataset <- data[data$ID == id, ]
          
          # Validate columns
          if (input$datatype == "Continuous" && any(is.na(dataset[, c("Dose", "Mean", "SD", "N")]))) next
          if (input$datatype == "Dichotomous" && any(is.na(dataset[, c("Dose", "Incidence", "N")]))) next
          
          if (input$datatype == "Continuous") {
            results_basic <- fit_continuous_models(dataset, "sd", input$bmr_level, tolower(input$fit_type))
            results_poly <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:4, function(d) fit_continuous_models(dataset, "sd", input$bmr_level, tolower(input$fit_type), degree = d)))
            all_results <- rbind(all_results, results_basic, results_poly)
          } else {
            results_basic <- fit_dichotomous_models(dataset, tolower(input$fit_type))
            results_multistage <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:3, function(d) fit_dichotomous_models(dataset, tolower(input$fit_type), degree = d)))
            all_results <- rbind(all_results, results_basic, results_multistage)
          }
        }
        results(all_results)  
      })
      
      output$results <- renderTable({
        req(results())  # Display results in the app
        results()
      })
      
      output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("results-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(results(), file, row.names = FALSE)  # Use reactive `results()`
        }
      )
    }
    

    shinyApp(ui, server)


When I try to deploy on shinyapps.io, I get the following error within RStudio:

── Deploying to server
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Waiting for
task: 1482595384   building: Processing bundle: 9418784   building:
Building image: 11564993   building: Installing system dependencies
building: Fetching packages   error: Building package: ToxicR
Begin Task Log
Quarto not found.
End Task Log
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1482595385
child_task_status=failed: Error building image: Error fetching ToxicR
(24.1.1.2.4) source.  unable to satisfy package: ToxicR (24.1.1.2.4)
Execution halted

I understand the main issue is shinyapps.io can't install the required package ToxicR during deployment, but I tried to address this within the server logic. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

You should not be installing packages on a Shiny app, ever. It will not work. Did you try just installing the package locally and checking if the deployment process just picks up the package and installs it too? Also, try setting up {renv} in your project, as that's what shinyapps.io uses to install dependencies. Check this out, too.

^ what they said. But I have also been encountering problems recently deploying apps with GH dependencies that worked fine before, so I think something might be broken on their side.

Thanks very much Bastian and smartse, and thanks for sharing the post! I had the package installed and loaded locally and I can't seem to run the app locally or deploy it.  I revised the code to exclude the installation on Shiny but again can't seem to run it.
